# Using "two days later" instead of "the day after tomorrow"

Tags: word-usage

I have a question whether you can use "two days later" instead of "the day after tomorrow" in certain sentences.

When you lend your bicycle to someone who is going to use it the next day, I think you can say

> Bring it back to me the day after tomorrow.

I am wondering if you can instead say

> Bring it back to me two days later.

Can you use the second sentence instead of the first?

Comment: "Bring it back to me in two days" is the most natural.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Two days *later* is relative to some point in time which must be specified. If you mean two days from the current time, you say "in two days" or "two days from now."

> Bring it back to me in two days.

> You can borrow it on Wednesday and bring it back to me two days later.